# JSON export truncates numbers to 6 digits of precision

Tags: export, version-10, json-format, version-10.1

**Update:** This problem was fixed in Mathematica 11.3.

---

It seems that in version 10.0.2 and 10.1.0, floating point numbers are truncated to only 6 digits of precision when exporting to JSON.

Example:

```
ExportString[RandomReal[1, 5], "JSON"]
(* "[
    0.832049,
    0.355306,
    0.615313,
    0.332704,
    0.186309
]" *)
```

What is a quick workaround?  I would expect about `$MachinePrecision` digits to be preserved.

Note: I have already reported this problem and support confirmed that it's a known issue.  I'm posting here to ask for temporary workarounds or existing alternative JSON exporters.

---

**Update:**

After some spelunking, it seems that the functions doing the actual formatting are these:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All the functions starting with `c` are implemented in C through LibraryLink, so I have no access to them.  I can override `cEncodeReal` and `cEncodeRealList`, but that only fixes single reals or lists of all reals.  All other expressions, including things such as `{"a" -> {1.2, 2.3}}` are fully handled by the opaque `cEncodeExpr`.

Reimplementing this function would mean pretty much reimplementing a *complete* JSON exporter in which case one might as well start from scratch and not use `Export`...

Comment: What if you export the `InputForm[]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. It fails, unfortunately. All formatting seems to be done in C.

Comment: @Szabolcs, have you filed a ticket w/ support?

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, in June 2015, i.e. the same time when posting this question.  At that time it was already a known issue, according to support.

Comment: @Szabolcs, is it resolved as of 11.3?

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, it turns out that it's still broken in 11.2, fixed in 11.3.

Answer (score 2):

At least in version 11.0.1.0 it is possible to just set `SetSystemOptions["MachineRealPrintPrecision"->Round[$MachinePrecision]]` without modifying any files. Note that only integers seem to be allowed.

Comment: I am having the same problem on a cluster where updating to a newer version of Mathematica is not an option. You are saying this fixes the issue? Where is the change saved? Or should it be set in every session? Can it be saved for one user only? (I cannot change the original Mathematica installation).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround until this gets fixed.

**WARNING:** Modifying installation files can break things. Do this at your own risk, and keep the modification in mind, in case you experience problems with JSON export later.  Do this only if you are affected by the problem.

Open the file

```
SystemFiles`Links`JSONTools`JSONTools.m
```

Skip to line 233, where the number of digits to be printed can be set on:

```
optionsList[[PRINTPRECISION]] = ...
```

Set it to 16 to preserve approximately `$MachinePrecision` digits.

(With a bit more work, this could conceivably be done without modifying installation files, through the `cSetOptions` function defined in the same file.  But I'm lazy and wanted a permanent solution anyway.)