# Slight loss of precision when parsing JSON

Tags: bugs, parsing, json-format, precision-and-accuracy

Exporting to JSON is working well for me under 11.3. The [issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85746/json-export-truncates-numbers-to-6-digits-of-precision) present in previous versions seem to be solved:

```
n1 = 1755.8118873183587;
json = ExportString[{"n" -> n1}, "JSON"]
(*
  "{
      \"n\":1.7558118873183587e3
   }"
*)
```

However, I do see a small loss of precision when I import this back:

```
n2 = <|ImportString[json, "JSON"]|>["n"];
FullForm[n2]
(* 1755.8118873183589 *)
```

Notice that the last digit is 9 instead of 7.

```
RealDigits[n1] === RealDigits[n2]
(* False *)
```

This small difference doesn't happen with other formats such as CSV:

```
{{n3}} = ImportString[ExportString[n1, "CSV"], "CSV"];
RealDigits[n1] === RealDigits[n3]
(* True *)
```

I am using Windows 10 and also reproduced this in the cloud.

Why is this happening? I am not sure that this is a bug as `n1==n2` returns `True`, but still, if there is a way to avoid this behavior I would like to know.

**UPDATE**: I have confirmed this issue with Wolfram Support [CASE:4231647]. In the meanwhile, I have found that the loss of precision can be avoided like this:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
"filename.json" // ReadString // JSONTools`FromJSON // ToAssociations
```

Comment: Check out `1.7558118873183587*10^3 // FullForm`.The float is read in, then multiplied by 10^3. In "CSV" the number is not stored in scientific notation and hence doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Avoiding machine precision seems to make the exporter avoid scientific notation: `json = ExportString[{"n" -> SetPrecision[n1, 17]}, "JSON"]`

Comment: Based on @ChipHurst comment, I think that in the JSON parser, the scientific notation `e` is being replaced by `*10^` instead of `*^`